# Standalone Razor Page url/encoding/render issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently working on a full blown MVC application and I have a standalone "coming soon" razor view folder with only one razor sharp html file.

Just to make it clear the simplified structure of the project is like this:

- Root

  - Controllers (folder)
  - Models (folder)
  - Views (folder)
  - splash (folder)

    - index.cshtml

inside splash it is only one file (index.cshtml) and some js/css folder used for that page.

I have added this line in the web.config to make the index.cshtml render as a standalone page.

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

Now this all works fine, but here comes the wierd part. 
When I am i debugging mode and navigate to **localhost:44300/splash/** the page renders fine (without adding index.cshtml to the url) and when I got to **localhost:44300/splash/index.cshtml** it also renders fine.

But when i publish the page I need the whole URL, including .cshtml for it to render as a razor view page. If I just go to **domain/splash/** it renders as wierd normal html page it looks like. But if I got to **domain/splash/index.cshtml** it works fine.

So the question is how can i get it to render the page perfect (as razor sharp html) with just navigating to **domain/splash/** ? And if possible, when you go to **domain/splash/index.cshtml** change the url to **domain/splash/**

Comment: is web.config in the splash folder or in the root one?

Comment: Have to check your outputs routes.

Comment: I only have one web.config file in the root directory. It's also one web.config file in the Views folder. The <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" /> line is there aswell.

Comment: Could you be abit more spesific @Inanikian? How do I do this? My ouput routes? I have no special routes added in the route.config file. But I dont think it uses the routes spesified here anyways(?)

Comment: Why won't you just create a controller called splash with index action and set it as default in Global.asax.cs?

Comment: Hmmm mostly because I would like to keep it seperated from the rest of the project. So it's easily to remove when its not needed anymore